# Sqlite ArrayList<Float> query run with AsyncTask

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I am trying to create a chart for my app and having trouble to load my data to the chart. It gives me a out of memory error. Then I have been trying to have the SQLite query run in the background thread by using AsyncTask. I tried but not able to create it correctly. I post my code here and hope somebody can help me on this. many thanks!!!!

here is the error message:

```
     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 103059952 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 53MB until OOM
                                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)
```

Here is the part of my code that provide me the data source. I am pulling data from SQLite database. The query works. I tested. I need to write the code that run the query in background thread by AsyncTask.

```
     public ArrayList<Float> yData(){
    ArrayList<Float> ynewData=new ArrayList<Float>();
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql="select sum("+ TableData.TableInfo.COL_S4_AMT+") MonthPieCHartCategoryValues,c."+ TableData.TableInfo.COL_C2_Description+" Category from "+ TableData.TableInfo.DataBase_Table_Spending+" s join "+ TableData.TableInfo.DataBase_Table_Items+" i on i."+ TableData.TableInfo.COL_I1_ItemID+"=s."+ TableData.TableInfo.COL_S3_ItemID+ " join "+ TableData.TableInfo.DataBase_Table_Category+" c on c."+ TableData.TableInfo.COL_C1_CategoryID+"=i."+ TableData.TableInfo.COL_I3_CategoryID + " where strftime('%Y',"+ TableData.TableInfo.COL_S2_Spending_DT+")=strftime('%Y',Date('now')) and strftime('%m',"+ TableData.TableInfo.COL_S2_Spending_DT+")=strftime('%m',date('now')) group by c."+ TableData.TableInfo.COL_C2_Description+" order by Category  desc";
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(sql,null);
    for(cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast();cursor.moveToLast()){
        ynewData.add(cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(MonthPieCHartCategoryValues)));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return ynewData;

}
```

Comment: obviously becuase you just created the infinite loop ... check your conditions twice before asking the question here

Comment: infinite loop? which part? I am new to Android and Java.

Comment: Seems like you have problems with logic's basics ... if you move something to last position at every iteration you will never hit "after last" position

Comment: I am very new to this field and learning. Thank you for your patient!! what this code tell me: for(cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast();cursor.moveToLast())

Comment: *what this code tell me:...*  i don't know, you wrote it ...

Comment: Sorry. I am embarrassed. I am learning code online. It is code that somebody wrote. I copy it and use it. The same thing that I used in different app, it works but the database less complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Selvin says, your loop will run infinite times since you are moving to the last element after every run of the loop. Try something like this :

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    ynewData.add(cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(MonthPieCHartCategoryValues)));
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: Many thanks Rhari!! I will try tonight and get back to you tomorrow.